# How can one check if a given quantum channel is unitary?

Tags: quantum-operation, entanglement-breaking-channels

A unitary channel is a channel $\mathcal{U}$ of the following form:
$\mathcal{U}(\rho) = U\rho U^{\dagger}$.

A  mixed unitary channel is a channel $\mathcal{U}_m$ of the form: $\mathcal{U}_m(\rho) = \sum_{k=1}^n p_kU_k\rho U_k^{\dagger}$, where each $U_k$ is a unitary matrix.

So given a general quantum channel, determining whether or not it is mixed unitary is an NP-hard problem. Is there any easy test to check if it is unitary?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean by an 'isometric' quantum channel?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the edits.   Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In the title, you ask "how one can check if a given isometric channel is unitary" but then in the question you state that "an isometric channel is a unitary channel". Are you just wondering when a mixed unitary channel has a single term in the sum?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the confusion. I have edited it and hope it is clear now. Given a quantum channel, I was wondering how we can check if it is unitary with only one term in the sum (not mixed unitary).

Comment: which problem exactly are you saying is NP-hard? Checking whether a given channel is isometric surely isn't no? Just check the rank of the Choi, as per the answer. And an isometric channel is a unitary channel iff the input and output dimensions are the same (I'm assuming the $A$ in your post is also an isometry, otherwise the map you get is not a (CPTP) channel)

Comment: Great.. it looks like I have managed to confuse everyone. I will try rewriting the problem in simpler terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compute the rank of the [Choi matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps) $C_\Phi$. For any quantum channel $\Phi$, the Choi matrix will be rank 1 if and only if $\Phi$ can be written in the form $U\rho U^\dagger$ for a unitary $U$.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies my doubt. Could you refer any material so that I can read more on this?

Comment: @HarikrishnanSV Watrous' book, https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/, is always a good reference

Comment: @HarikrishnanSV as pointed to by glS in the comment above, Watrous' book is an excellent reference and should provide all the relevant information and background. I believe chapters 2 and 4 discuss quantum channels and mixed-unitary channels.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.